# Hibernate: выбирать из БД не все поля

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, lazyloading

Возможно ли в Hibernate такое:
При получении Entity из БД выбирать не все поля а только некоторые, чтобы снизить нагрузку на базу?
Например, при логине пользователя нам не нужно "тянуть" из БД все его атрибуты, нужны поля только login и password. При редактировании профиля пользователя, конечно же, выбираем все поля таблицы users.

Возникла идея - создать в коде две сущности - одна UserSmall(id,login,password) а вторая User с полным набором полей.
Но догадается ли Hibernate что это ссылки на одну и ту же таблицу и будет ли синхронизировать сущности?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь оптимизировать то, что не тормозит ваше приложение. От уменьшения трафика на условные 10% вы в целом и этих 10% не выиграете.

Comment: Вы можете пометить даже простые поля для ленивой загрузки, можете загружать проекции (массивы или классы с нужными полями, точнее конструкторами. тот же класс что entity можете задействовать, но экземпляр не будет entit-ей), можете определить ещё одну (и более entity) на той же таблице, но только с нужными полями (синхронизировать навряд ли  не будет). Нет преграды для героя. Ну и конечно обратить внимание на первый комент.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно замапить 2 сущности на одну таблицу, и Hibernate догадается, что эти 2 (или более) сущности указывают на ту же таблицу. Для этого используется аннотация `@Table(name = "table_name")`.
Нет, они не будут синхронизированы в том смысле, что, если одновременно активны две сущности  - `User` и `UserSmall` - изменения из `User` не попадут в `UserSmall` магическим образом (нужно будет селектнуть `UserSmall` после сохранения `User`, чтобы получить обновленные данные).

Е̶с̶л̶и̶ ̶п̶о̶п̶ы̶т̶а̶т̶ь̶с̶я̶ ̶с̶о̶х̶р̶а̶н̶и̶т̶ь̶ ̶з̶а̶п̶и̶с̶ь̶ ̶с̶ ̶н̶е̶п̶о̶л̶н̶ы̶м̶ ̶н̶а̶б̶о̶р̶о̶м̶ ̶п̶о̶л̶е̶й̶ ̶в̶ ̶б̶а̶з̶у̶,̶ ̶т̶о̶,̶ ̶г̶е̶н̶е̶р̶и̶р̶у̶я̶ ̶з̶а̶п̶р̶о̶с̶,̶ ̶в̶ ̶о̶с̶т̶а̶л̶ь̶н̶ы̶е̶,̶ ̶н̶е̶з̶а̶м̶а̶п̶л̶е̶н̶н̶ы̶е̶ ̶п̶о̶л̶я̶,̶ ̶H̶i̶b̶e̶r̶n̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶п̶о̶д̶с̶т̶а̶в̶и̶т̶ ̶`null`.  (**правка**: см. комментарии)
Поэтому одну из них, `UserSmall`, я рекомендовал бы пометить аннотацией `@Immutable`, чтобы предотвратить случайное сохранение в базу. Так как скорей всего она будет использоваться вами только для чтения.
Ещё может пригодиться аннотация `@DynamicUpdate`. Она позволяет ̶с̶е̶л̶е̶к̶т̶а̶т̶ь̶ ̶и̶ ̶сохранять в базу неполную запись (в примере ниже см. `UserUpdatable`, ̶в̶ ̶к̶-̶м̶ ̶с̶о̶х̶р̶а̶н̶я̶т̶с̶я̶ ̶и̶з̶м̶е̶н̶е̶н̶и̶я̶ ̶т̶о̶л̶ь̶к̶о̶ ̶в̶ ̶п̶о̶л̶я̶х̶ ̶`firstName`̶,̶ ̶`lastName`). (**правка**: см. комментарии)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    // все поля
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Immutable
public class UserSmall {
    // id, login, password
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@DynamicUpdate
public class UserUpdatable {
    // id, firstName, lastName
}
```

---

1. Документация [`@DynamicUpdate`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/DynamicUpdate.html)
2. Документация [`@Immutable`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Immutable.html)

Comment: _"генерируя запрос, в остальные, незамапленные поля, Hibernate подставит null"_ - Hibernate (условно) ничего не знает о полях, которые не описаны в классе, и, соответственно, не может подставить для них 'null'. При генерации SQL-запроса для сохранения, обновляться будут только замапленные поля, а остальные будут отсутствовать в тексте запроса вообще.

Comment: @bobzer, мда, похоже вы правы. В чём тогда смысл `@DynamicUpdate`?

Comment: При указании '@DynamicUpdate' в SQL-запрос попадают только изменённые поля. Например, в классе сущности указан маппинг 10-ти полей таблицы. Осуществили чтение из БД, изменили значение только одного из полей и выполнили сохранение. В SQL-запросе 'UPDATE' в разделе 'SET' будет указано только одно поле, то которое изменили, остальных 9-ти - не будет. У аннотации есть свои ограничения, связанные с тем, что Hibernate должен как-то отслеживать состояние сущности. '@DynamicUpdate' не сработает, например, для detached сущностей.